# Blue background of question poster comment away after edit

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, design, inline-editor

I'm sorry for nitpicking but this is just something to make Stack Overflow even more perfect :)

If the question poster has posted a comment (e.g. under an answer), his/her name has a lightblue background to emphasise this. However, if you edit your answer, the blue background has gone.

Before edit:

[image: Before edit]

After edit:

[image: After edit]

Perhaps this could be fixed, just for consistency.

Comment: Good eyes; well spotted.

Comment: [Your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654190/gather-div-class-into-a-javascript-array/6654228#6654228) looks fine to me. In your picture, it looks like your JavaScript did not completely execute, since the color syntax highlighting is also missing in your edited answer.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: The syntax coloring is missing too indeed. It is all solved when refreshing the page though, so probably you won't see it if you just navigate to the answer.

Comment: Right.  So something got munged when the answer was edited.  Probably the relevant JavaScript just needs to be re-executed.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: Not sure what's happening behind the scenes, but just for the record I don't get any JavaScript errors.

Comment: wow, nice eyeS!

Comment: I've found that the sites have been lagging a lot these past two days at around this time for quite a while.  The page never completely loads until you refresh it.  That includes page content, ads, javascripted stuff, etc.  I figured it was a problem with the server but it might be worth mentioning.

Comment: @Jeff Mercado: I'm also experimenting this currently.

Comment: @pimvdb: It turns out [there seems to be some connection problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98264/is-it-just-me-or-are-the-sites-having-connection-problems).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in latest, also takes care of allowing you to see the comments during edit and also fixes the syntax highlighting issue.